# Showing and Syncing Hamburger Icon from fragment in Navigation View?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

This is my `activity_main.xml`. It has a Navigation View and FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The below codes are from `MainActivity.class`

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Handling Click in Navigation drawer Items :

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_updates) {

            UpdatesFragment fragment = new UpdatesFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
      } .. and so on
```

The `UpdatesFragment` has a view along with the toolbar. I mean i'm repeating toolbar for each and every fragment.

In the `onCreateView` method of `UpdatesFragment`, I use this code to show the toolbar which I've written especially for `UpdatesFragment`.

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppCompatActivity activity = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity());
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My questions are :

1. It shows the Toolbar, but there's no hamburger Icon.
2. I want to have a hamburger icon and if i press, it should open Navigation drawer as espected.

Note : I'm again repeating i didn't use common toolbar. When i do fragment transaction, I replace everything including toolbar. Every fragment has toolbar. Toolbar is showing. Only hamburger Icon and it's action is missing.